# Segmentation fault while using strncat in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I just started learning two weeks back and am basically a beginner. So I wrote this program. But it continuously gives Segmentation fault error line 41 in the strncat function. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>

#define WORD "/usr/share/dict/words"

int error(void);
int check(char *text, char *psswrd, char *salt);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return error();

    char salt[3]; 
    salt[0] = argv[1][0];
    salt[1] = argv[1][1];
    salt[2] = '\0';

    FILE *fptr;
    char ch;
    char *word;
    int flag = 0;
    fptr = fopen(WORD, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            ch = fgetc(fptr);
            if ( ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')
            {
                word = strncat(word, &ch, 1);
                if (strlen(word) == 8)
                {
                    flag = check(word, argv[1], salt);
                    if (flag == 0)
                    {
                        printf ("%s \n", word);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                word = "";
            }
        }
        while (ch != EOF);

        fclose(fptr);
    }

    if (flag == 2)
    {
        printf("Password not found\n");
        return 2;
    }
}

int error(void)
{
    printf ("Usage: ./crack <encrypted keyword>\n");
    return 1;
}

int check(char *text, char *psswrd, char *salt)
{
    if (strcmp(crypt(text, salt), psswrd) == 0 )
        return 0;
    else 
        return 2;
 }
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `word`.

Comment: Just add one line like `word = (char *) malloc(<memsize>);`

Comment: For `ch == EOF` to work, `ch` must be an `int`, not a `char`. But if you make it an `int`, you won't be able to use it as an argument to `strncat`. (To my mind, that doesn't matter. `strncat` is a *terrible* way to append a character to a string whose length you know.)

Comment: @rici Thats the only way that I know right now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SayantanTalukder: `s[i++] = ch; ` is unknown to you? You don't seem to have a problem using that syntax with `salt`.

Comment: @rici Actually no. It isn't unknown. I was just being stupid. I was so lot in the trying to add up a string and char ,I totally forgot I can just treat the string as an array of chars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate a memory buffer for "word":

```
word = malloc(MaxInputSize);
```

Or better would be to just declare word as a static array:

```
word[MaxInputSize];
```

Comment: Thanks. The static array worked. (Actually I found the use of array easier to understand)

Comment: Don't forget to free it.

Answer (score 1):

on doing

```
char *word;
```

you have declared word as a pointer to char but you have not set where `word` points to. As long as unassigned `word` can point to anywhere and de-referencing `word` ie `*word` causes undefined behavior and that is exactly what you did in

```
 word = strncat(word, &ch, 1);
```

For the code to work properly you need to allocate memory to `word` before the above step ie  do something like

```
word=malloc(100*sizeof *ptr); // You set word to point to a chunk of 100 bytes
```

Assuming `word` to point to a chunk of 100 bytes, now

```
strncat(word, &ch, 1);
```

wouldn't be logically correct, because assuming word is completely filled( 99 characters plus terminating null character), you can't add one more character to it, so you need to have some error checking prior to this step. Do something like

```
if strlen(word)<=98)  // remember 99 is the max allowed, you gonna add 1 char
  strncat(word, &ch, 1);
```

---

And as a good practice, you could delete the memory after use, ie

```
free(word);
```

Comment: You always want to free the memory after you are done.

Comment: @Mirakurun : Well,as a good practice, yes, but they will be automatically freed when the program ends anyways

Comment: Not only as a good practice, also for not running out of memory (if the memory does not need to be allocated untill the end of the program)

Comment: @sjsam Don't take memory as granted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `word`, either as an array or using `malloc`. If the string is small (compared to your stack size), use an array, as it doesn't require cleanup.

You also need to set `word[0]=0;` after `malloc`, otherwise you'll get junk and a possible second segmentation fault.

The canonical way of adding characters to a string is

```
char word[9];
char* pWord = word;
memset(word,0,sizeof(word));
...

  ch = getchar();
  *pWord++ = ch;
  len++;
  if (len >= sizeof(word)-1) ...
```